# Vue Build fails to include scss

Tags: vue.js, build

I'm working on a vue.js app. It runs fine in DEV mode, but fails to include / parse my scss while Building (npm run build). I'm using the the Vue PWA template (https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa)

My scss is included in the App.vue file like so:

```
<style lang="scss" src="./styles/app.scss">
```

I've haven't changed anything in the build/config files.

Should i add my app.scss file as a seperate entry point, I'm quite lost here..|

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `node-sass` and `sass-loader` is already setup correctly.

You can use the following way to import your `sass` file

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import "./path/to/scss"
</style>
```